# Отобразить FancyBox окно в полную высоту?

Tags: jquery, fancybox, css

Как отобразить всплывающее окно в зависимости от его содержимого на 100%?

Я пытался применить опцию `'height': '100%'`, но это показало только окно в полный размер окна браузера, контент, который не поместился, не отобразился.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    fixed : false,
    autoCenter : true,
    fitToView : false //вот этот параметр вставить нужно
});
```

Вот эти параметры сделают окно на всю высоту